# How does de OS know which solution to apply to a concurrency problem?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, resources, scheduling

When x1, ..., xN proceses try to access some A resource, how does the OS know the particular solution to use for handling the issue of concurrency?

If A is serially reusable then the solution can be a mutex semaphore, but how does the OS identify A as serially reusable? And what's the logic used for creating and accessing the structures used for handling its concurrent use?

How does it do the same thing for resources that match the other concurrency problems: producer-consumer, readers-writers, and philosophers.

Comment: An operating system knows nothing of "concurrency problems." The choice of algorithm and strategy to solve any particular problem is up to the application program developer(s). The OS is just a box of tools that program developers can use however they see fit.

Comment: Then wouldn't it be really easy for a malicious process to meddle in other processes by requesting access to a shared resource without checking for any concurrency issues?

Comment: Yes. For example, an OS will only allow one process at a time to `listen` on TCP port 80. If you try to run two web servers, both listening to port 80, whichever one opens the port first will "win," and the other one will "lose." Or, if some application A overwrites files that were created by application B, then that will interfere with the operation of application B. A system administrator can somewhat limit the ability of one application to interfere with another by controlling permissions, but the best thing is to not run malicious software on your computer (if you can avoid it.)